# Finding the probability of point S forming a triangle with A and B in a square.

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

> Let $S$ be a point chosen at random from the interior of the square $ABCD$, which
> has side $AB$ and diagonal $AC$. Let $P$ be the probability that the segments $AS$, $SB$,
> and $AC$ are congruent to the sides of a triangle. Then $P$ can be written as : $$\frac{a-\pi\sqrt b-\sqrt c}{d}$$ where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are all positive integers and $d$ is as small as possible. Find $ab + cd$.

I am having trouble understanding what they mean by "congruent to the sides of a triangle". I assumed that it means they form a valid triangle. Then $AS+SB > AC$ must be true. Intuitively this makes me think of an ellipse with foci at $A$ and $B$ but it's unclear how I'll use this idea further. Can someone explain the idea or suggest an approach?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It means that it is possible to construct a triangle with side lengths $AS,~SB,~AB$, i.e.   $|AS-SB| \le AB \le AS+SB$. The joint law of the random variables $X := AS$ and $Y := SB$ can be found, since for every positive real numbers $x$ and $y$, the event $[X \le x ; Y \le y]$ holds if and only if $S$ belongs to the intersection of two circles (and of the square). So you have to compute areas (in a few different cases) to get the joint distribution function.

Comment: @achillehui I think the idea that $OP$ has about sum of focal distances to a point on the ellipse being equal to the length of its major axis works well here.

Comment: Problem can be solved without using calculus with the fact that ellipse is elongated circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplification, we take square $ABCD$ with vertices $~A (- 1, 0), B (1, 0), C (1, 2) \text { and } D (-1, 2)$

[image]

Now we draw an ellipse centered at the origin (midpoint of $AB$) with major axis along x-axis and equal to $|AC|$ and minor axis equal to $|AB|$. Then points $A$ and $B$ are focii of the ellipse. Regardless of the position of point $S$ inside the square, $AC$ will be bigger than both $AS$ and $BS$ as $AC$ is the diagonal. So if we choose point $S$ such that $|AS| + |BS| \gt |AC|$, the three segments will make a triangle. As $AS$ and $BS$ are focal distances, the inequality must hold true for all points $S$ outside the ellipse.

So, to find the desired probability, calculate the area of square $ABCD$ outside of the ellipse and divide by the total area of the square.

Equation of the ellipse is
$~ \displaystyle \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{1} \le 1$

I will use substitution $x = \sqrt 2 r \cos\theta, y = r \sin \theta$

Jacobian of transformation $|J| = \sqrt2~$ and the ellipse transforms to unit circle $~r \leq 1$

We will first find area of the segment of the ellipse in the first quadrant, right to $BC$. Line $x = 1$ (which passes through $BC$) can be rewritten as,

$ \sqrt2 r \cos\theta = 1 \implies r = \dfrac{\sec\theta}{\sqrt2}$

At intersection of the line and the ellipse,
$\sec\theta = \sqrt2 \implies \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$

So area of segment in the first quadrant is,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_{\sec \theta / \sqrt2}^1 |J| ~ r ~ dr ~d\theta = \frac{\pi-2}{4 \sqrt2}$

Using formula for the area of the ellipse, we can find area of the ellipse above x-axis and then subtract two half segments at both ends. That gives us area shaded in the dark gray. We also know that area of the square is $4$. So, area shaded in light gray can be computed as,

$ \displaystyle 4 - \left(\frac{\pi \sqrt2}{2} - \frac{(\pi - 2) \sqrt2}{4}\right) = \frac{16 - \pi \sqrt2 - 2 \sqrt2}{4}$

So, $P = \dfrac{16 - \pi \sqrt2 - \sqrt8}{16}$